# Expo KeyboardAvoidingView Android - Stuck on navigation

Tags: android, react-native, expo, keyboard

I'm currently building my *"forgot password"* flow where i spotted the following issue.
When the user enters his email the KeyboardAvoidingView works just fine on IOS and Android **(Image 1)**. But when the user has an active Keyboard, clicks on continue and navigates back the KeyboardAvoidingView does something weird **(Image 2)**. The input is staying at the top of the screen. Important to say. The ForgotPasswordScreen doesn't get unmounted when navigating to the next screen and coming back.

```js
<SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <KeyboardAvoidingView
    behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
    style={{
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: "flex-end",
      paddingHorizontal: 20,
    }}
  >
    {children} -> Here is my page code
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
</SafeAreaView>
```

If more code is needed please let my know.

Anybody noticed this kind of a issue?

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57cm2.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EUOB.png)